# Add values if condition column is true

Tags: mysql, sum, addition

I have a MySql query that looks like this :

```
SELECT o.id, 
       o.priorytet_1 + 
       o.priorytet_2 +
       o.priorytet_3 AS bonus 
FROM obiekty o 
WHERE o.ac=1 
GROUP BY o.id 
ORDER BY `o`.`id` ASC
```

next to `priorytet_1, priorytet_2 and priorytet_3` columns I have `priorytet_1_valid, priorytet_2_valid, priorytet_3_valid` where I store date, to which for example `priorytet_1` is valid.

And I want to add only those columns, which date is `< now()`.

Something like :

```
SELECT o.id, 
       if (o.priorytet_1_valid < now()) o.priorytet_1 + 
       if (o.priorytet_2_valid < now()) o.priorytet_2 + 
       if (o.priorytet_3_valid < now()) o.priorytet_3 AS bonus 
FROM obiekty o 
WHERE o.ac=1 
GROUP BY o.id 
ORDER BY `o`.`id` ASC
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT o.id, 
       SUM(IF (o.priorytet_1_valid < NOW(), o.priorytet_1, 0) + 
           IF (o.priorytet_2_valid < NOW(), o.priorytet_2, 0) + 
           IF (o.priorytet_3_valid < NOW(), o.priorytet_3, 0)) AS bonus
FROM obiekty o 
WHERE o.ac=1 
GROUP BY o.id 
ORDER BY `o`.`id` ASC
```

You probably want to use `SUM` since you have a `GROUP BY` clause. The `SUM` function used in the query above *conditionally* adds fields `o.priorytet_1, o.priorytet_2, o.priorytet_3` in case the corresponding 'valid' field is older than the current date/time.